# Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild Hadoop3.0.0

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to run hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.0.0.jar to a hadoop cluster (hadoop3.0.0),but I see the error as Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.

command:hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.0.0.jar pi 2 10

below image is my error details

[image: Exception]

```
<!-- core-site.xml --> 
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://master:9000</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/tmp/hadoopdata</value>
</property>

<!-- hdfs-site.xml -->
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>3</value>
</property>

<!-- yarn-site.xml  -->
    <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>master</value>
</property>

<!-- mapred-site.xml -->
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
    <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME</value>
</property>
```

I do not set the HADOOP_CLASSPATH,and I don't know whether or not it's problem

Comment: 1) Look at the YARN UI to inspect if there are other errors 2) Hadoop 2.9.0 is the current stable version

Comment: Thanks!
but,there's no other errors.
I will try hadoop 2.9.0.
Thank you again for answered my question.

Comment: Hey, did you find solution for this other than switching to a different hadoop version?

Answer (score 2):

you should add property to yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>yarn.application.classpath</name>

<value>
/opt/module/hadoop-3.1.3/etc/hadoop,
/opt/module/hadoop-3.1.3/share/hadoop/common/*,
/opt/module/hadoop-3.1.3/share/hadoop/common/lib/*,
/opt/module/hadoop-3.1.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/*,
/opt/module/hadoop-3.1.3/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*,
/opt/module/hadoop-3.1.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*,
/opt/module/hadoop-3.1.3/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*,
/opt/module/hadoop-3.1.3/share/hadoop/yarn/*,
/opt/module/hadoop-3.1.3/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*
</value>
</property>
```